# How does one show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

How does one show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ converges? I have a book that uses this to define $e$ but they don't show that it converges. I suppose we could give it an upper and lower bound but I don't know how to do this. I've seen this question before on here but I haven't seen an answer I like yet.

Comment: As witnessed unvoluntarily by the two answers instantly posted below, to address your question requires to know the tools available to you. IOW, what do you know about the logarithm, say?

Comment: The properties of the natural log have not been defined yet.

Comment: "I haven't seen an answer I like yet."  Wow. I admire your chutzpah. I would have thought that any correct and clear answer (and there are plenty of those) would suffice. I'm not sure I'm prepared to delve into the realm of personal aesthetics, and I *certainly* am not if you don't tell me the criteria in advance. This becomes something other than a math problem.

Comment: Consider buying Spivak's *Calculus*. It treats this material quite nicely.

Comment: I found a pdf of it online John, I will check it out.

Comment: For example, a low-tech approach is to consider $$x_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k}n\right)$$ and to show that $(x_n)$ is increasing and bounded above by $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}$$ Both proofs are elementary. Then remains to extend this to every nonnegative real $x$, which is also elementary.

Comment: FYI, I voted to close your question because it is a typical example of a post lacking of context, probably due to laziness.

Comment: What do you mean by lack of context Did?

Comment: @David you should provide context for your question, which means that you should tell us: where did your question come from? why are you interested in it? what have you tried? what tools are available to you?

Comment: You may tried this video to how the existence of $e$ could be guessed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuA2EAgAegE

Comment: "The properties of the natural log have not been defined yet" Which is the reason why you accept an answer **based on these properties**, I guess? Well done.

Comment: I am very surprised that there was no answer which does not already assume the existence of $\exp$, $\log$ or $e$ itself. As Did said, your accepted answer does not fit your own requirements and there are certainly better ones, e.g. the approach which Did presented in one comment. I am sure that he or someone else is willing to explain it in full details when he sees that you not just accept *any* answer. As it is now, the  motivation is quite low.

Comment: @M.Winter: I wrote such an answer (without using log/exp) at first but later decided to close the question and deleted my answer also. If the OP is willing to modify the question to meet this website expectations, then I will undelete the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $h =\frac1x\to 0~~as ~~x\to\infty$ Then, 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac1x}\right) =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1+h\right)}{h}\right) = e$$

Given that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+h\right)}{h} = 1$$

**Edit:** For OP doubt. I think he to know how can want guess the existence of $e?$ without appealling $\ln$ and $\exp$.

> In fact Euler Predicted the existence of $e$ before the creation of the functions  $\ln$ and $\exp$: it is explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuA2EAgAegE

Comment: I think you mean $1,$ not $0$.

Comment: Don't we have to know that the limit converges to some number $e$  before we use the log of $e$? As I said, this limit is used to define $e$. What if it diverges? Then it makes no sense to use the natural log in that case.

Comment: There are many definitions of $\ln$; one is that $\ln (x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$, which is known to exist (for $x > 0$) by the fundamental theorem of calculus, and even is known to be differentiable with derivative $\frac{1}{x}$ (by that same theorem), hence is a strictly increasing function. It's not even tough to prove it's a surjection from $R^{+}$ to $R$, hence invertible. Then one can **define** $e$ to be $ln^{-1}(1)$, and prove that it equals the limit you're wondering about.

Comment: @David It will be helful you let us konw how you want to define $\ln$ and $\exp$.

Comment: I define $e$ as that limit. The natural log has not yet been defined in my book. I just though that perhaps it could be shown that the limit exists without using $e$ and ln but I guess that's not the case. I'll define ln first and see what I can do.

Comment: Ok I See.Now  How do define this function $x\mapsto a^x$ without log and Exponential?

Comment: In fact it is possible to predict the existence of e but in the way you thing see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuA2EAgAegE  Good watching

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\ln b = \int\limits_1^b\frac{dx}{x}$ with $b = 1+\frac{1}{n}$ then

$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) = \int\limits_1^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\frac{dx}{x}$

The area represented by this integral lies between the area of two rectangles of height $\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $1$ and base $\frac{1}{n}$. These rectangles have areas $\frac{1}{1+n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$, therefore:

$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\frac{1}{n}$

Multiplying through by $n$ and using $n\ln a = \ln a^n$:

$\frac{n}{n+1}\leq\ln\left((1+\frac{1}{n})^n\right)\leq1$

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1} = 1$ the middle quantity must approach $1$ by the squeeze theorem:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln\left((1+\frac{1}{n})^n\right)=1$

Now apply the continuous function $e^x$ to obtain the desired result:

$e^1 = e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln\left((1+\frac{1}{n})^n\right)} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{\ln\left((1+\frac{1}{n})^n\right)} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Check out Rogawski Calculus section 7.5 pp 374-375.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$A=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\implies \log(A)=x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ and use equivalents $$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\sim \frac{1}{x}$$ making $$\log(A)\sim 1\implies A \sim e$$